# AsyncStorage not getting into then() method in react native

Tags: react-native, asynchronous

It seems like the async await doesn't work in react native. When I run the code below, it just logs 'here", not the value.

```
class CompanyDetails extends Component {
   ...

   componentDidMount = async () => {
        await this.getCompDetailsData();
   }

   getCompDetailsData = async () => {
            console.log('here');
        await AsyncStorage.getItem('CompanyID')
          .then((value) => {
              console.log(value);
            const compID = JSON.parse(value);
                console.log(compID);
            this.props.getCompDetails(propID);
        });
    };
    ...
```

Does anyone know why it is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you had 'CompanyID' stored somewhere before because if you did not store it before then it will go to the catch part which is not implemented in your case

```
getCompDetailsData = async () => {
            console.log('here');
        await AsyncStorage.getItem('CompanyID')
          .then((value) => {
              console.log(value);
            const compID = JSON.parse(value);
                console.log(compID);
            this.props.getCompDetails(propID);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log("CompanyID is not defined yet");
        });
    };
```

Comment: I added the catch and it is not going to the catch also.

Answer (score -1):

You may not have a saved value in that name "CompanyID"

Comment: Yes, I set the value in my login page.